# How to get text content of multiple <td> tags inside a table using PyQuery?

Tags: python, pyquery

How to select attribute's text field from given book-details table field where values are in  text or in  text field?

```
    <table cellspacing="0" class="fk-specs-type2">
        <tr>
            <th class="group-head" colspan="2">Book Details</th>
        </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                <td class="specs-key">Publisher</td>
                <td class="specs-value fk-data">HARPER COLLINS INDIA</td>
            </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                <td class="specs-key">ISBN-13</td>
                <td class="specs-value fk-data">9789350291924</td>
            </tr>

                </table>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use following code snippet to get `Publisher` and `ISBN-13` data:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

html = """<table cellspacing="0" class="fk-specs-type2">
        <tr>
            <th class="group-head" colspan="2">Book Details</th>
        </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                <td class="specs-key">Publisher</td>
                <td class="specs-value fk-data">HARPER COLLINS INDIA</td>
            </tr>
                                                                                    <tr>
                <td class="specs-key">ISBN-13</td>
                <td class="specs-value fk-data">9789350291924</td>
            </tr>

                </table>
"""

doc = PyQuery(html)

for td in doc("table.fk-specs-type2").find("td.specs-key"):
    print td.text, td.getnext().text
```

It should print following two lines

```
Publisher HARPER COLLINS INDIA
ISBN-13 9789350291924
```